# How to execute an event in CodeBehind being called by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have this code in **Aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite.View.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Projeto para Testes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dvEventos" class="dvEventos">
            <h1>Apenas um teste</h1>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEventoCsharp" CssClass="btnEventoCsharp" Text="Evento C#" OnClick="btnEventoCsharp_Click" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnEventoCsharpByJS" CssClass="btnEventoCsharpByJS" Text="Evento C# by JS" OnClick="btnEventoCsharpByJS_Click" runat="server"  />
            <button id="btnEventoJqueryClick" class="btnEventoJqueryClick">Evento C# by Jquery</button>
            <button id="btnEventoJquery" class="btnEventoJquery">Evento Jquery</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CarregaEventosIndex();
    });

    function CarregaEventosIndex() {
        $('.btnEventoJquery').off('click').on('click', function () {
            alert('Event click by Jquery');
        });

        $('.btnEventoJqueryClick').off('click').on('click', function () {
            $("input[id*=btnEventoCsharpByJS]").click();
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

My file **CodeBehind**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebSite.View
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void MetodoSemParametroChamadoEventosDiferentes()
        {
            string passeiAqui = "sem parametro";
            string evento = passeiAqui;
        }

        /// Evento de Teste
        protected void btnEventoCsharpByJS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MetodoSemParametroChamadoEventosDiferentes();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Webforms, and I need to call a CodeBehind event through jQuery, in this case using this btnEventoJqueryClick button. But there is one, however, if I use this code $ ("input [id * = btnEventoCsharpByJS]"). Click (); Through the browser console, using breakpoint in CodeBehind I realize that the event is called, but clicking the button is not calling the event. What am I doing wrong? Or, how can I call a CodeBehind event through jQuery differently?

Comment: on thing to check would be the network tab. When you click the buttons see if any network traffic is being sent to your server and verify the response. Compare the network traffic between the click and the click generated by the console. Another possible cause is a ID conflict. make sure there aren't any other buttons on the page or master page with conflicting IDs. Good luck!

Comment: How about you try this  `$("#<%=btnEventoCsharpByJS.ClientID %>").click();` instead of `$("input[id*=btnEventoCsharpByJS]").click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET by using `ClientID`.

```
$("input[id*=btnEventoCsharpByJS]").click();
```

Should be:

```
$("#<%=btnEventoCsharpByJS.ClientID %>").click();
```

Thus you can trigger CodeBehind method `btnEventoCsharpByJS_Click`